# How block the site and display a banner for users who doesn't use javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, security, frontend

I wanted to know if there is a way to redirect users who don't enable JavaScript in their browser for security questions.
I know that you can use the `<noscript>`tag, but I just wanted to know if there is another way. If there is no other way, just let me know it! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`noscript`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp) html tag can be used to display a message when javascript is turned off.

Another approach could look like this:

```
<div id='noscript'>show non-js content</div>
<script>document.getElementById('noscript').style.display='none';</script>
```

Where the message/element is hidden if javascript is off.

Comment: Yes, but does the page will still be displayed?

Comment: try it! <noscript></noscript> ftw!